# Does javascript of jquery have a way to call an unequals variable?

Tags: jquery, javascript

there seems like there should be an easy way to do this.  I'm switching class names on some other elements and tying this change to that action.  I have the i variable set that initiates a fade in, but would like to fade out on which ever other numbered ids there might be.  Is there a quick way to do this, perhaps a symbol that says to perform a change on anything that doesn't equal this i variable?  Or a generic number symbol that would perform the action before I begin the fade in?

```
$('#SiteDescriptions' + i).animate({opacity: "1"}, 500);
$('#SiteDescriptions' + !i).animate({opacity: "0"}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use id's and rely on selectors. Instead use classes:

```
 $SD = $('.SiteDescription'); // cache jquery object
 $SD.on('click',function(){
     // fade out all with this class
     $SD.stop().animate({opacity:0},500);
     // fade in new active element 
     $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},500);
 });
```

If you try to select anything but that id, you will be selecting every element on the page that is not it. And I don't think that is what you want.

Don't do it this way, do it the class way, but this is closer to what you are asking:

```
$('#SiteDescriptions'+i).animate({opacity : 1 },500)
 // I don't want to speculate on your dom structure, but if you are using id's
 // you still need a way to prevent from fading out everything on the page that
 // isn't the new action. So I am assuming that all the #SiteDescriptions are siblings
.siblings().not('#SiteDescriptions'+i).animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If `i` is `boolean`, use ternary operator

```
$('#SiteDescriptions' + i).animate({opacity: (i) ? "1" : "0" }, 500);
```

Comment: This seems to be a valid option to me, not sure who down voted. +1

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Assume i = 1. He wants to select the other elements (#SiteDescriptions2, #SiteDescriptions3, ...) and apply the opposite opacity to those elements.

Comment: @user113215 When the OP says this way: `!i` he's converting it to boolean!!! How do you say it is not a boolean?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No - he's saying in his question "it's some other number that is not i".

Comment: I see you've updated your answer to qualify _if i is boolean_... but it's not.  Read the question, where OP states _but would like to fade out on which ever other numbered ids there might be_ and then only ever uses `i` in the context of a numbered ID: `$('#SiteDescriptions' + i)` or _anything that doesn't equal this i variable_ `$('#SiteDescriptions' + !i)`  And even if it were boolean, how would that work in the ID?

Comment: Exactly! I have no clue for answering his question. I don't understand.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry didn't see your response 'till now.  I always like to explain my downvotes, this is why I'm still replying after all this time has passed! ;-).  OP was effectively writing _pseudo-code_, using `!i` to mean "all the other [#SiteDescription] numbers that are present, but that are not `i`".  Perhaps he should have _explicitly_ stated that his example was pseudo-code, but (in my humble opinion) this was clearly implied by his question text.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you want:

```
$('#SiteDescriptions' + i).animate({opacity: "1"}, 500);
$('[id^=SiteDescriptions]').not($('#SiteDescriptions' +i)).animate({opacity: "0"}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `startsWith` selector and `not()`. Also `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are same as `animate` of opacity

```
var site = $('#SiteDescriptions' + i).stop(true,true).fadeIn( 500);
$('div[id^="SiteDescriptions"]').not(site).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500)
```

Also not sure what trigegrs the animations...use `stop()` if possibility that an animation is in progress when you call another animation on same element

Comment: This looks like the best way to do it without modifying the HTML, although I'd still recommend the OP make SiteDescription a class as the preferred approach.

Comment: Works, but ouch dats durty.

Comment: @Fresheyeball nothing dirty about it

Comment: @charlietfl maybe I am mistaken, but regex in a selector kinda dirty? And .stop(true,true) ?